# How to use Display Metrices In Dialog Class

Tags: android, dialog, android-alertdialog

I have a class which extends Dialog class of android. And my problem is that I want to use Display metrics for height and width but I am not able to use it.

Code in which I have issue. I have problem in second line:

```
DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
context.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
```

Comment: exactly what is the problem/error with the second line you are having ?

Answer (score 0):

try Using this instead of your code see if it helps :

```
DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
```

or

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        windowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:

```
DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();

dialog.getWindow().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
```